# How to reuse a fragment after orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently trying to reuse created fragments after an orientation change. My layout on a tablet consists of **3 columns**. The **first** is a simple navigation drawer, the **second** is a list and the **third** is a details view for items selected in the list.

My aim is to remember the selected item in the list after an orientation change from landscape to portrait to landscape. In the portrait mode the selection is not shown.

Have a look at my code:

```
mListFragment = (RecordingListFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("tag");

if(mListFragment == null) {
    mListFragment = new RecordingListFragment();
}

if(mDetailsFragment == null) {
    mDetailsFragment = new RecordingDetailFragment();
}

// phone
if(!mTwoPanelsUsed) {

    // pop from back stack or create
    if(!fm.popBackStackImmediate(BACK_STACK_STATE_LIST, 0)) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mListFragment, "tag");
        ft.addToBackStack(BACK_STACK_STATE_LIST);
        ft.commit();
    }

// tablet
} else {

    // container got invisible in other cases, so make visible again
    findViewById(R.id.container_2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // pop from back stack or create
    if(!fm.popBackStackImmediate(BACK_STACK_STATE_LIST_AND_DETAILS, 0)) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container_1, mListFragment, "tag");
        ft.replace(R.id.container_2, mDetailsFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(BACK_STACK_STATE_LIST_AND_DETAILS);
        ft.commit();

    }

}

// store index pressed in navigation drawer for back button navigation
mNavigationDrawerActivatedHistory.push(NAVIGATION_RECORDINGS);
mDrawerNavigationPosition = NAVIGATION_RECORDINGS;
```

By executing this I get an runtime exception for the line

```
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mListFragment, "tag");
```

named:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID
>   of fragment RecordingListFragment{d0e629e #1 id=0x7f0a0043 tag}: was
>   2131361859 now 2131361856

I already read something about remove the fragment and then executePendingTransactions. Changing the code to

```
if(mListFragment == null) {
    mListFragment = new RecordingListFragment();
} else {
    fm.beginTransaction().remove(mListFragment).commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

results in another exception:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.iav.viraprecorder/com.iav.viraprecorder.VIRAPRecorderActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to
>   executePendingTransactions

How can I restore the state of my fragment?
(I dont want to use the retainInstance thing)

Thanks!

Comment: Add your manifest to question ;)

Comment: I think this is not necessary. I have got only one activity and this one changes dynamically fragments.